# How to exchange and authenticate ephemeral public keys with tweetnacl?

Tags: python, c, encryption, public-key-encryption

The C library http://tweetnacl.cr.yp.to/ for strong ECC encryption written
and published by Daniel J.Bernstein is very neat and small.

Using it from Python is even easier with the tweetnacl Python interface module written and published by Jan Mojžíš : https://mojzis.com/software/python-tweetnacl/index.html

Generating ephemeral public and secret key pairs is very easy:

```
python
>>> import tweetnacl as nacl
>>> pk, sk = nacl.crypto_box_keypair()
```

Assuming Alice got Bobs public key and vice versa then encrypted communication using the `crypto_box()` and `crypto_box_open()` functions 
is pretty straight forward and easy to implement.

But I wonder:  What is easiest way to get Alice "`pk`" from here to 
Bob and the public key of Bob back to Alice?  How can Bob be sure that
a received public key is really the key of Alice and vice versa?

Comment: Key exchange does not appear to be part of the library.

Comment: I recently watched a talk of D.J.Bernstein : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj3PN5-n108 (Paper here: http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/bada55/bada55-20140722.pdf ).  In this entertaining talk DJB speaks about providers as „man in the middle“.  So I'm now looking for a cryptographically safe way to implement such a key exchange.

Comment: That's what signatures are for, which the library provides with Ed25519. One side must *trust* the other side. What's your trust anchor?

Answer (score 1):

You can't without a trusted third party and another secure channel. That is the reason SSL has certificate authorities and trust-chain certificates pre-deployed in the browser. Without those, the exchange process is vulnerable to an active man in the middle.